# How do I generate an APK for local distribution in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, production

I'm working on a dev team that provide workers and workstations with the software tools they need, we don't sell our apps to the public, we distribute our apps locally using an ftp server as a repository, we don't need to sign or upload our software to the cloud, how could we generate the APKs for our apps, so we can host them locally to be downloaded and installed manually on each device by clkicking on the apk file?

Comment: You can easily generate it through Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you install it on a device or distributed through PlayStore, you have to sign that Application before it can be opened by device.

`Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they are installed on a device or updated`. more: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

To sign your Application, see this tutorial -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android